# create index based on condition in python

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x, pandas

I have data of **5 weeks(35 days)** with me where the **start_date** (1-AUG-2016) is the first date of first week and end_date( ) is the last date on the 5th week. Also i have the hourly data from (say **0 - 23**).

```
day date(dd-mm-yyyy)  hour
1    01-01-2016       0
1    01-01-2016       1
1    01-01-2016       2
1    01-01-2016       3
1    01-01-2016       4
1    01-01-2016       5
1    01-01-2016       6
.
.
1    01-01-2016       23
.
.
35   04-02-2016       0
35   04-02-2016       1
.
.
```

And i want to create and index that it counts up till my selected hours (say 3 - 5) and adds 1 to the next index. But the moment it hits non selected hours it should retain its last value. something like this.

```
day date(dd-mm-yyyy)  hour  Index 
1    01-01-2016       0     1
1    01-01-2016       1     1
1    01-01-2016       2     1
1    01-01-2016       3     2
1    01-01-2016       4     3
1    01-01-2016       5     4
1    01-01-2016       6     5
1    01-01-2016       7     5
1    01-01-2016       8     5
.
.
1    01-01-2016       23    5
2    02-01-2016       0     5
2    02-01-2016       1     5
2    02-01-2016       2     5
2    02-01-2016       3     6
.
35   04-02-2016       0
35   04-02-2016       1
.
.
```

Can we do this in python using loops. we might need to sort the data by day,date and hour. I know this is simple but i am stuck. can we also create a lookup for sequence of date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you can use:

```
print (df)
    day date(dd-mm-yyyy)  hour
0     1       01-01-2016     0
1     1       01-01-2016     1
2     1       01-01-2016     2
3     1       01-01-2016     3
4     1       01-01-2016     4
5     1       01-01-2016     5
6     1       01-01-2016     6
7     1       01-01-2016    23
8    35       04-02-2016     0
9    35       04-02-2016     1
10   35       04-02-2016     2
11   35       04-02-2016     3
12   35       04-02-2016     4
13   35       04-02-2016     5
14   35       04-02-2016     6
15   35       04-02-2016     7
```

```
#create list for lookup
hours = [3,4,5]
hours = hours + [hours[-1] + 1]
print (hours)
[3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Check values by [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) and then [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
print (df.hour.isin(hours))
0     False
1     False
2     False
3      True
4      True
5      True
6      True
7     False
8     False
9     False
10    False
11     True
12     True
13     True
14     True
15    False
Name: hour, dtype: bool
```

```
df['Index'] = df.hour.isin(hours).cumsum() + 1
print (df)
    day date(dd-mm-yyyy)  hour  Index
0     1       01-01-2016     0      1
1     1       01-01-2016     1      1
2     1       01-01-2016     2      1
3     1       01-01-2016     3      2
4     1       01-01-2016     4      3
5     1       01-01-2016     5      4
6     1       01-01-2016     6      5
7     1       01-01-2016    23      5
8    35       04-02-2016     0      5
9    35       04-02-2016     1      5
10   35       04-02-2016     2      5
11   35       04-02-2016     3      6
12   35       04-02-2016     4      7
13   35       04-02-2016     5      8
14   35       04-02-2016     6      9
15   35       04-02-2016     7      9
```

Comment: Can you add desired output from my sample to question?

Comment: done , can you please check the row where day start at 2, ideally it should be 5 , but in your code the moment it will hit 0, it will add one to it.

Comment: Super awesome and simple. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do a counter that should look like this, depending on how your data is structured. I would assume that you have made a list of the hours?

```
 hours = [0,1,2,3,4,5...,23]
```

You could make a list of what you want to find like this

```
 select = [3,4,5] //This is your  selection list.
```

Then run a for loop through the select list.

```
count = 0
for i in select:
    if i in hours:
        count+=1
```

*So if you want to count for the rest of the weeks, you can multiply by the total number of days, which I assume would be number of days in a week multiplied by the number of weeks.*

```
    count = count*7*5
```

Im sorry if this answer does not meet your requirements, I cannot add comments yet! But this is the best I can give